# GNU/Linux using comm with a file and the output of a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, archlinux, comm

I want to use the comm command to compare a text file and the output of a command.

My first idea was to run:

```
comm packagesList $(pacman -Qe)
```

However, that outputs an errpr. I also tried using `´pacman -Qe´` just in case, but I still get the same error.
Is there a way for me to compare the contents of the text file packagesList against the output of the `pacman -Qe` command?

Comment: generally speaking the statement `doesn't work` isn't very useful; for us to understand the issue better it's best if we're also told what `doesn't work` means, eg, error/syntax message(s) (include text in question)? no output? wrong/unexpected output (include in question)? one/both of the files not sorted? something else?

Comment: Hello mark; I see what you mean. I have corrected the question, despite it being quite old. I hope it's more understandable now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pacman -Qe | comm packagesList -
```

or

```
comm packagesList <(pacman -Qe)
```

Topics to research: what are standard streams and stdin/stderr/stdout, `man comm` -> `When FILE1 or FILE2 (not both) is -, read standard input`, what are *command substitution* and *process substitution* terms in shell context.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and the tips!
The latter option is more familiar to me, so I'll use that.

Have a good day. I'll mark your answer as correct ASAP